# How to put onclick event on a button whose values is coming from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add click event of change color when clicked on label but the values of label comes from database. So how may I do the same?

```
 <legend>Roti</legend>
 <?php
     $qu = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=33") or die(mysql_error());
     while($f = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
 ?>
 <p>
     <label for="name"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>
     <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>">
 </p>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You attach a handler to the event by means of javascript. That is independent from a buttons value.

Comment: Can't spot a button in that code...

Comment: ok but one more question is that if i want to display the value of that particular clicked element to another div or page...then how may i do this...

Comment: Indeed that is a completely different question. And it should be asked separately. That is, _if_ you really have to ask a question for this at all, since there are many, many examples for such things on the internet.

Comment: yes i know @arkascha but as i am a fresher in this field so i have got no idea about this.Still if anybody can help me out then it will be helpful for me

Comment: Everyone starts once :-) You are welcome. But "should be asked separately" is pretty clear to understand. Do not combine questions. Ask them separately.

Comment: ok got it thanks @arkascha

Answer (score 1):

**use onclick and give a function name(here i use changeColor() as function** name) shown below

```
<label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label> <!-- #### REPLACE THIS LABEL CODE INSIDE WHILE LOOP -->



<script>  //########### add this outside while loop...usually just above closing body tag </body>
    function changeColor(obj){
        obj.style.color = "red";
    }

</script>
```

> This will change label color on clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by two methods:

**1. Javascript**

```
<label for="name" onclick="return color(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>

<script>
function color(lbl)
{
    lbl.style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

**2. Jquery**

```
<label for="name" id="lab">Test</label>

<script>
$( "#lab" ).click(function() {
    $('#lab').attr('style','color:#ff0000;');
});
</script>
```